# Opening pdf files from S3 bucket using a URL link

Tags: pdf, amazon-s3

I wonder if anyone can help. I'm currently working on a project where we have a load of pdf documents in an S3 bucket. What i would like to be able to do is to open the link to each pdf automatically, however the link to each document is:

[s3://squad-dataops-analysis-restricted-cdp-us-east-1/FAA_CDs/data/manual_23092022_test_all_pred/out/14032022/ocr_pdfs/14032022_0558.pdf](https://s3://squad-dataops-analysis-restricted-cdp-us-east-1/FAA_CDs/data/manual_23092022_test_all_pred/out/14032022/ocr_pdfs/14032022_0558.pdf)

but this doesn't open straight into a pdf reader as the link is s3://

This is how we have the pdf files in the folder in the S3 bucket:

[image]

This what each individual pdf property in S3 looks like:

[image]

if i click the Object URL link in the property section i get the following:

[image]

Is there something I need to change in the S3 bucket policy to get this to work? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want a public S3 bucket (if fully public is not what you want, see the link towards the end). In order to make all objects public you must:

- Navigate to the 'Permissions' tab of your bucket in the S3 console
- Disable/uncheck 'Block public access (bucket settings)'
- Add a statement to your bucket policy to allow `getObject` requests

Your bucket policy should look something like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

After you do this, you should see the 'Publicly accessible' flags on your bucket and you'll be able to access objects with the object URL.

[image]

[This article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/) goes into more depth on object access.